What's the benefit of using the Pythagorean predictions over the linear predictions?
Not sure this is a suitable question in data science stack exchange post (if so, apologize for that and I really appreciate if you guide me the right place), but I am wondering what's the benefit of using the Pythagorean predictions over the linear predictions in the baseball analysis/sabermetrics.
In Analyzing Baseball Data with R (3e), it says:

The RMSE calculated on the Pythagorean predictions is similar in value to the one calculated with the linear predictions.
The the Pythagorean predictions is more complex compared to a simple linear model and not more accurate.
The Pythagorean expectation model, however, has several desirable properties missing in the linear model.

and refer to some an example which is not realistic in the actual baseball game (like the author himself pointed out in the same book). Thus, to me, it's not very clear what's the actual benefit of using the Pythagorean predictions over a simple linear model. I understand that we can easily say "if you don't want to use the Pythagorean predictions, then you don't have to use it (and just stick to the linear model...)" to my question here but wanted to see if someone could help/guide me here. Any feedback more than welcomed. Thanks so much for your time in advance!

I have absolutely no experience with baseball data, but reading the information on the linked page to me it seems that the Pythagorean predictions are just more robust to extreme scenarios.
